# GLSL Texture for minecraft

Tags: glsl, textures, minecraft

I would like to make my minecraft textures ps2 style, with texture warping but only modify the textures. Is it possible ?

I found this article, I would like to do this again:

https://danielilett.com/2021-11-06-tut5-21-ps1-affine-textures/

Comment: Are you talking about PS1 or PS2?

Comment: I'm talking about ps1

Answer (score 1):

The "warping" you see is the result of incorrect interpolation across the surface of a triangle. If the triangle is not large relative to the screen size, then interpolation won't have very far to go. And thus, you will see very little if any effect.

In a game like Minecraft, you generally draw the surface as a series of quads (technically, the middle of a triangle in the quad). Thus, the effect would only be in the middle of a quad. Unless you are very close to one of those quads, using `noperspective` will likely not create much of an effect, even in a corridor-like area.